# Fixing Composer: Can't resolve packages

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

After submitting my first packagist package, I ran into a problem when I tried to use it in a new Laravel project (v4.2). Was there anything I forgot to add/remove in my package `composer.json` file?

I wanted to use my new package but got this instead:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for enchance/messageman dev-master -> satisfiable by enchance/messageman[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v4.0.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.11
    - enchance/messageman dev-master requires illuminate/support 4.2.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.1|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.11
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.12|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.11
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.16|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.11
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.17|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.11
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.2|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.11
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.3|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.11
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.4|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.11
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.5|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.11
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.11
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.11
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.8|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.11
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.9|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.11
    - Installation request for laravel/framework == 4.0.11.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.0.11].
```

My package's `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "enchance/messageman",
    "description": "A simple message sending package for use within a system.",
    "keywords": [
        "laravel"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "enchance",
            "email": "enchance@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "license": "MIT License",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "illuminate/support": "4.2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "src/migrations"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "Enchance\\Messageman\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Comment: I think is for  "minimum-stability": "stable" switch to dev-master

Comment: How do I make it work with `"stable"`? By the way, the composer file I posted is my package's. It only has one branch which is `master.`

Comment: I'd also try to remove `/vendor` dir, then run `composer install`.

Comment: I saw the problem--I wasn't using 4.2 after all, I was using a much older 4.0. By changing my package to use `"illuminate/support": "4.0.*"` fixed everything.